# A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'testDB_KYC3Model.ts_upld_doc' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Fields'

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller

I am getting below error.
A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'testDB_KYC3Model.ts_upld_doc' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Fields'.

This is my ts_upld_doc class.

```
 public partial class ts_upld_doc
    {
        string _template;

        public ts_upld_doc()
        {
            this.tr_upld_content = new HashSet<tr_upld_content>();
        }
        public List<tr_doc_content> Fields { get; set; }

        public int upld_docid { get; set; }
        public int usr_createdby { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> upld_clientid { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<tr_upld_content> tr_upld_content { get; set; }
}
```

this is my tr_doc_content class

```
public partial class tr_doc_content
    {
        public int doc_contentid { get; set; }
        public int doc_typeid { get; set; }
        public string doc_contenttypelabel { get; set; }
        public string doc_ctrltype { get; set; }
        public string doc_fieldtype { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> doc_isrequired { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> doc_isactive { get; set; }

        public virtual tm_doc_type tm_doc_type { get; set; }
    }
```

I have on more class with some functions written in it.

```
public DbDrivenView(string viewName)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("viewName", new ArgumentException("View Name cannot be null"));
            }
            _viewName = viewName;
        }

        public void Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
        {

            ts_upld_doc dataForm = dbContext.ts_upld_doc.Include("Fields").First(f => f.upld_employeename == _viewName);
         var sb = new StringBuilder();
            var sw = new StringWriter(sb);
            using (HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
            {
                htmlWriter.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div);

                foreach (var item in dataForm.Fields)
                {
                    htmlWriter.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div);
                    htmlWriter.WriteEncodedText(item.doc_contenttypelabel);
 htmlWriter.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Id, item.doc_ctrltype);
                    htmlWriter.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Name, item.doc_ctrltype);
                    htmlWriter.RenderEndTag();
                    htmlWriter.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div);
                }htmlWriter.RenderEndTag();
            }
            writer.Write(dataForm.Template.Replace("@DataFields", sb.ToString()));
        }
```

when i debug this code I am getting below error Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'testDB_KYC3Model.ts_upld_doc' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Fields' near this line of code.

```
ts_upld_doc dataForm = dbContext.ts_upld_doc.Include("Fields").First(f => f.upld_employeename == _viewName);
       Please help me in sorting out this.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Entity Framework does not know that "Fields" is a foreign key relation. Try to explicitly expose this relation in the ModelBuilder, e.g.

```
ModelBuilder.Entity<ts_upld_doc>().HasMany(d => d.Fields).WithRequired();
```

If lazy loading is enabled, make sure to mark this collection as `virtual`.